# Invertibility of $I-A^s$ for each $s \geq 1$ implying nilpotence

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, alternative-proof, nilpotence

If $R$ is a unital ring and $x \in R$ a nilpotent element, then $1-x$ is a unit, and so is $1-x^s$ for any $s \geq 1 $ since powers of $x$ are again nilpotent.

My question concerns the converse of this statement in the case in which $R = M_n(\mathbb{C})$, that is:

> **Question 1:** if $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a square matrix with complex entries and $I-A^s$ is invertible for all $s \geq 1$, what conditions can we impose on $A$ to guarantee that it is nilpotent?

Some condition has to be in place, as the general statement is already false in dimension $1$. In that case, the matrices $1-a^n$ will be always invertible whenever $a$ is not a root of unity, and the only nilpotent element is zero. More generally, any diagonal matrix $\mathrm{diag}(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ of non-zero elements that are not roots of unity will do the trick.

Here's a partial result,

> If $\{\det(I-A^n)\}_n \subset \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ converges, then either the spectrum of $A$ is contained in $B_1(0)$. In particular,
> if $A$ has integer coefficients then it is nilpotent.

A proof follows: let $c_n := \det(I-A^s)$ and $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n \in \mathbb{C}$ be the eigenvalues of $A$, counted with multiplicity. Then

$$
(1-\lambda_1^s) \cdots (1-\lambda_n^s) = c_s 
$$

is a convergent subsequence. Noting $d_s = \prod_{i \ : \ |\lambda_i| \neq 1}(1-\lambda_i^s)$, we then have

$$
\prod_{i \ : \ |\lambda_i| = 1}(1-\lambda_i^s) = c_s/d_s \to L.
$$
with either $L = 0$ or $L = \lim_s c_s$, depending on whether there are eigenvalues with absolute value greater than $1$. If has some eigenvalue outside the unit disc, the right hand side converges and moreover the left hand side has some non-trival factor.

Observe that since $c_n$ is never zero, no $\lambda_i$ can be a root of unity; and so we are left with showing that if $k \geq 1$ and $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_k \in [0,1)$ are irrational then

$$
a_s := \prod_{j = 1}^k(1-e^{i2\pi\alpha_j s}) 
$$
does not converge to $0$ nor $\lim_s c_s$.

By Dirichlet's approximation theorem, for each $k \geq 1$ we can find a natural number $s_k$ and an integer $p_k$ for which $|s_k\alpha_j - p_k| < 1/k$, and thus there is a subsequence $(s_k)_k$ for which $e^{i2\pi\alpha_j s_k} \to 1$ for all $j$, and $a_{s_k}\to 0$. But then taking $s'_k = s_k+1$ yields $e^{i2\pi\alpha_j s_k'} \to e^{i2\pi\alpha_j s}$ and $a_{s_k'} \not \to 0$. Hence $(a_s)$ *never* converges.

> Are there results in this direction whose proof is purely algebraic? In particular, can we recover the former partial results without *doing analysis*?

It seems to me like there is some relation between the spectrum of $A$ and the fact that $I-A^s$ being invertible implies the invertibility of $\sum_{i = 0}^s A^i$, the limit of the latter - were to exist- being the inverse of $I-A$.

> Is there a reference for this statement, at least in the case in which $\det(I-A^s) = \pm 1$ for each $s$ and $A$ has integer coefficients?

I suspect this specific case can be proved in a purely algebraic fashion but so far I haven't been able to come up with a proof. Here's what I've done so far:

- Suppose that $f = \chi_A = X^m g, g = (X-\lambda_1) \cdots (X-\lambda_k)$ with $X \not \mid g$. Note $p^{(m)}$ the polynomial whose roots are the $m$-th powers of $p$'s roots. Then our hypothesis is precisely that $f^{(m)}(1)$ is always a unit in $\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, the same holds for $g$, write $g = p_1 \cdots p_r$
  where $p_j \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ are irreducible. Since no eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ is a root of unity, once again by [Kronecker's  theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10911/english-reference-for-a-result-of-kronecker)  each $p_j$ has a - possibly complex - root of absolute value greater than $1$. Moreover the proof notes that in general if $p \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ then $p^{(m)} \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$, so in any case, we have
  $$
  \pm 1 = g^{(m)}(1) = p_1^{(m)}(1) \cdots p_r^{(m)}(1)
  $$
  and so $p_j^{(m)}(1) = \pm 1$. This allows us to reduce the original problem to:

> **Attempted Subproblem 1.** Let $f = \prod_{i=1}^k (X-\alpha_i) \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ be an irreducible monic polynomial. If $f^{(m)}(1) = \pm 1$ for each $m \geq 1$, where $f^{(m)} = \prod_{i=1}^k (X-\alpha_i^m)$, then $f = X$.

- Since $\det(I-A^s) = \pm 1$ for all $s$, dividing by $\det(I-A)$ gives
  $\det(\sum_{i=0}^s A^i) = \pm  1$ for all $s$. This yields a pretty large sum of all monomials $x_{i_1}^{j_1} \ldots x_{i_r}^{j_r}$ where $\{i_1, \ldots, i_r\} \subset \{1,\ldots, k\}$ and $j_t \in \{0,\ldots, s\}$, being equal to $\pm 1$. Maybe there's some underlying interpretation in terms of symmetric polynomials.

Comment: For $A=\mathrm{diag}(a_1,...,a_n)$ with $|a_i|<1$ for all $i$, isn’t $A$ still satisfies the assumption and even the determinant sequence converges to 1?

Comment: Yes, my bad. Originally my matrix $A$ had integer coefficients and so that implies that if there are non-zero eigenvalues, some has absolute value $> 1$.

Comment: The border case happens when $k = 0$ (i.e. no eigenvalues with absolute value 1) and there is no such eigenvalue as before.  I.e. precisely when all eigenvalues are non-zero but lie inside of the open unit disk. I'll fix this in a bit.

Comment: @SeewooLee I think I've fixed this now. My original motivation was to show that if $A$ has integer coefficients and $I-A^s$ is invertible for all $s$, then $A$ is nilpotent. If I am not mistaken, this is guaranteed by the partial result, even with this fix: the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is of the form $X^n g$ with $X \not \mid g$. If $g \neq 1$, then it must have a root with absolute value > 1 by Kronecker's theorem. I'd very much like a proof of this that does not involve Dirichlet approximation

Comment: The condition that $I - A^s$ is invertible for all $s \geq 1$ is equivalent to the condition that no eigenvalue of $A$ is a root of unity. This still seems very far from nilpotency. Something that _would_ guarantee nilpotency is a stronger condition like $\det(tI - A) = t^n$, which can be seen as requiring that $tI - A$ is invertible for all $t \neq 0$.

Comment: @Joppy I mean, yes, but requiring $\det(tI-A) = t^n$ is *equivalent* to nilpotence

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely say that if $I-A\cdot P(A)$ is invertible for every $P$ polynomial in $A$, then $P$ is nilpotent. Or: if $I - Q(A)$ is invertible for every polynomial $Q$ with $Q(0) = 0$, then $A$ is nilpotent. Since otherwise, let $\lambda\ne 0$ an eigenvalue of $A$, and $Q$ polynomial, $Q(0) = 0$, $Q(\lambda) = 1$. We get
$I- Q(A)$ has an eigenvalue $1- Q(\lambda) = 1-1=0$.

Comment: Thanks, this is very interesting. But just to be clear: the condition you state is not implied by having $I-A^s$ invertible for all $s$, right?

Comment: @guidoar:No, it isn't...  Note that if all the eigenvalues of $A$ are $<1$ in absolute value then certainly $I-A^s$ invertible for all $s\ge 1$ integers.  So there are lots of matrices like this ( spectral radius $<1$) Now, nilpotent means : spectral radius $=0$. So it is still rather far.   You can say this: $I-A^s$ invertible for all integers $\ge 1$ iff $A$ does not have any eigenvalue that is a root of $1$.  Note that if it has some eigenvalues of abs value $1$, but not roots of $1$, then again $I-A^s$ will be invertible, but then its eigenvalues can become very small.

Comment: Ah, right, $I-A^s$ being always invertible means exactly that $A$ has no root of unity as an eigenvalue. In any case, thanks for your contribution, this is a nice consequence.

Comment: @guidoar:  If we look at the Jordan canonical form of $A$, then all the $\lambda$ blocks of $A$ for $\lambda \ne 0$ become (equivalent to ) $\lambda^s$ blocks of $A^s$.  In any case, if $A$ is upper triangular, then $A^s$ also is, and we can see the eigenvalues. In any case, $A$ is conjugate to an upper triangular one ( over $\mathbb{C}$ in general). Glad it helps.

Comment: Yea, via Jordan forms the condition may be stated equivalently as: given complex numbers $z_i$ such that $\prod 1-z_i^s$ is always $1$; when is $z_i = 0$ for all $i$?

Comment: My bad, I meant $\prod 1-z_i^s$ is always non-zero, I was thinking about the subcase in which $\det(I-A^s) = 1$ for all $s$.

Comment: @guidoar: I see... But it is indeed interesting to prove that if $\det(I-A^s) = 1$, for all $\s\ge 1$ natural, then $A$ is nilpotent. I think it is true...

Comment: Yes, I think it does, I originally needed it for when the determinant is $\pm 1$; the sign varying on $n$, and I think an argument similar to the one in the question works. But I would really prefer a proof not relying on Dirichlet approximation, writing it in detail is rather cumbersome

Comment: @guidoar: I see... very interesting... you could ask it as a separate question:-- if $\det(I-A^m) = 1$ for all $m\ge 1$ natural, show that $A$ is nilpotent --. It is interesting, and I don't see a proof at the moment.