# On algebraic integers and minimal polynomials with roots that satisfy $\prod_{i=1}^n (1-\alpha_i^s) = \pm 1$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

This question in inspired on a particular case of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3987205/invertibility-of-i-as-for-each-s-geq-1-implying-nilpotence) post, which is:

> If $A$ is an integer coefficient matrix such that $I -A^s \in \mathsf{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ for all $s$, is $A$ nilpotent?

As stated there, if $f = \chi_A = \prod_{i=1}^n(X-\alpha_i)$ the hypothesis is precisely that

$$
\prod_{i=1}^n(1-\alpha_i^s)  = \pm 1 \tag 1
$$

for all $s \geq 1$. Or noting $f_m = \prod_{i=1}^n(X-\alpha_i^m)$, that $f_s(1) = \pm 1 $ for all $s$.

In general, we know that for any $g \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ the coefficients of $g_m$ are integers, hence factorizing $f$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ into irreducible factors $p_1,\ldots, p_r$ we get $f_m = (p_1)_m \cdots (p_r)_m$ and thus $(p_j)_s(1) = \pm 1$ for all $j$ and $s$.

Hence we can assume $f$ to be irreducible; $f = m(\alpha, \mathbb{Q})$ for some algebraic integer $\alpha$, recovering the question in the title:

> If $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ is an algebraic integer and $f =  m(\alpha, \mathbb{Q})$ is such that $f_s(1) \in \mathbb{Z}^\times$ for all $s \geq 1$, is $f = X$?

In the linked post, an argument using Dirichlet approximation and taking limits for a subsequence of $(1)$ shows (if correct) that $f = X$, but I am asking whether there is an algebraic proof of this, and more importantly, if there is an available reference for such a result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $K = \mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)$.
By assumption $f(x) \ne x$ so $\alpha \ne 0$. Let $\mathcal{O}$ be the ring of integers of $K$.  Since $\alpha \ne 0$, it only lies in finitely many prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}$.  Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal in $\mathcal{O}$ not containing $\alpha$ of residue characteristic $p$, and let $\mathbf{F}_q = \mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{p}$ be the residue field. Since $\alpha \ne 0 \bmod \mathfrak{p}$, it follows that $\alpha^{q-1} \equiv 1 \bmod \mathfrak{p}$ and so $1-\alpha^m \equiv 0 \bmod \mathfrak{p}$ if $m$ is divisible by $q-1$. But then

$$N_{K/\mathbf{Q}}(1 - \alpha^m) = \prod (1 - \alpha^m_i) \equiv 0 \bmod p$$

for any $m$ divisible by $q-1$.

Comment: (you meant $\alpha$ a non-zero root of $f$ which exists if $A$ is not nilpotent)

Comment: @reuns From the question "Hence we can assume $f$ to be irreducible".

Comment: Hi, I hope you don't mind answering some follow-up questions. I get the gist of the argument, but since my acquaintance with algebraic number theory is close to nonexistent, I would like to check that I'm understanding everything alright. First off: why does $\alpha$ lie on finitely many prime ideals? Maybe this follows from some generalities on commutative rings. On the same note: when you say residue *field*, the ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ is maximal because $\mathcal{O}$ is Dedekind right?

Comment: (cont.) Also, how do we know that the residue field is finite? And where are you using that $\alpha$ lies in **finitely** many primes? Doesn't your argument use a only fixed non-zero prime? Maybe there's something I'm missing.

Comment: @guidoar : The rings of integers $\mathcal O_K$ in general is a Dedekind domain, which means it satisfies the unique factorization property for ideals; an ideal can be factored uniquely (up to permutation of the factors) into a finite product of prime ideals. The prime ideals that contain a given ideal are precisely the prime ideals that appear in its (unique) factorization. Therefore, it can only be contained in finitely prime ideals.

Comment: Oh, right, so the prime ideals are "explicitly" the factors of $(\alpha)$, no?

Comment: Also note that the assumption that there is a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ of $\mathcal O$ that doesn't contain $\alpha$ is correct because rings of integers like $\mathcal O_K$ admit infinitely many prime ideals (each prime number $p \in \mathbb Z$ gives rise to an ideal $(p)$ which factors as a product of primes in $\mathcal O_K$, and each prime in $\mathcal O_K$ lies above precisely one prime number).

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I understand that such an ideal exists (because as you say, if $\alpha \neq 0$ we can factorize $(\alpha)$ as product of prime ideals, hence $\alpha$ lies in any of them). My question was rather (i) why do such primes have finite residue fields and (ii) aren't we only the fact that there exists *at least one* prime containing $\alpha$?

Comment: @guidoar : (ii) Sure, but there exists at least one because there are infinitely many options and only finitely many that don't work. You could use a more direct argument where you compute one, but that's an easy statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118625/discussion-between-guidoar-and-patrick-da-silva).

Comment: @guidoar : For (i), consider the inclusion map $\mathbb Z \to \mathcal O_K$. Let $(p)$ be the prime ideal in $\mathbb Z$ be above the prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ in $\mathcal O_K$. Then $(\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak p) / (\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)$ is a finitely generated algebraic field extension, and therefore is finite. This is the kind of stuff you study in commutative algebra when discussing integral extensions and Cohen-Seidenberg theorems.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva perfect; yeah, most of these things ring a bell *once I've read them* haha. Thanks for taking the time to answer. One last question: is there a citable source on the solution this problem? I don't mind if it's a nuke - i.e. way more general - as long as I can cite it, or if it takes little work to observe the conclusion from a citable result

Comment: @user868719 Hi, sorry for the late reply. I am very satisfied with your answer. Nonetheless, I am looking for a citable source that includes/implies this result. For this reason I've started a bounty, in case you can help me with that. Again, thanks for your contribution